# multiple targets for assignment operators in Python?

Tags: python, variable-assignment, operator-keyword

Is there a way in Python to use assignment operators for multiple targets (operands) like this:

```
a, b, c += d
```

with `d` being something expensive in terms of memory and computation time?
If not, what is the Pythonic way to do it and calculate `d` only once without saving it in a new variable?

Comment: No, there isn't a way to do that. The pythonic way is to save it in a new variable.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers! As it turns out from some of your answers, there's no performance penalty when assigning d to a new variable and operator-assign it to a, b, c one-by-one (or in a loop). So, I'll do it like that.

Comment: @ZacDiggum in general assignment itself is not expensive in python. The only instance would be if a large memory allocation had to be made, but that would typically happen for the computation anyway. Attribute lookups and global lookups can sometimes have a measurable performance penalty, so it is advisable to perform computation in a function where variables are in a local scope, and will be automatically de-referenced when they go out of scope. All of this usually falls under "premature optimization" however. Algorithmic optimization is far more useful.

Comment: @Aaron Thanks for reminding me of the "premature optimization" trap. You might have a point here. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
a, b, c = a+d, b+d, c+d
```

Comment: Thanks Taohidul, but I'd like to compute d only once and keep it in a temporary array without assigning it to a variable.

Comment: @ZacDiggum assigning to a variable local to a function uses the python "store_fast" opcode which is very inexpensive resource-wise. It is more readable, and you are not actually loosing performance, so there is no reason not to assign to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
a, b, c = 0, 0, 0
d = 8
a, b, c = map(lambda x: x+d, [a, b, c])
print(a, b, c)  # 8, 8, 8
```

Answer (score 0):

This would have the intended effect I believe, but I'm not sure what you would gain by doing it.

```
a, b, c = (n+d for n in (a, b, c))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = 1 
b = 2
c = 3
z = 1

[a, b, c] = [i+z for i in [a, b, c]]
print(a, b, c)
```

The output is

```
2 3 4
```